# remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure (Identity server Hosted in azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I tried a lot and now putting it here .. so I have an app service in which API Identity server and UI(Blazor) is hosted in different folders inside the same app service now i generated the rsa signing cert from
[https://damienbod.com/2020/02/10/create-certificates-for-identityserver4-signing-using-net-core/](this blog post)
now everything works fine on development even when i set hosted identity server as provider and localhost(UI and Web API) even then its working
but when i try to access the hosted API its throwing error (in log) and i am getting 401
[image]

please any helps would be appreciated

also

my identity server startup looks like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var settings = config.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
        X509Certificate2 rsaCertificate = null;
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            rsaCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
            Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "cert/rsaCert.pfx"), "password");
        }
        else
        {
            using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
            {
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                    settings.CertificateDetails.CertificateThumbPrint,
                    false);
                // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
                if (certCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    rsaCertificate = certCollection[0];
                }
            }
        }
        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();
        services.AddDbContext<SeatingDBContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(x =>
        {
            x.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            x.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<SeatingDBContext>().
     AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x =>
        {
            x.Cookie.Name = "IdentityServer.Cookie";
            x.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        });

        var assembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name;
        services.AddIdentityServer(x =>
        {
            x.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            x.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            x.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            x.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        }).AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
  .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Configuration.GetIdentityResources())
  .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configuration.GetApiScopes())
   .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.GetApis())
   .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetClients(settings.ClientApps))
   .AddSigningCredential(rsaCertificate);
// .AddValidationKey(rsaCertificate);

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(Repository<,>));

        services.AddTransient<IUserSyncService, UserSyncService>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

and my web API looks like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var settings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<SeatingDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(Repository<,>));
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(settings.EmailConfiguration);
        services.AddScoped<MailSender>();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddIdentityForWebApi<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(x =>
        {
            x.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            x.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<SeatingDBContext>();
         
        services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme:"Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", config =>
        {
            config.Authority = settings.ODICSettings.Authority;
            config.ApiName = settings.ODICSettings.Audience;  
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                foreach (string scope in settings.ODICSettings.scope)
                    policy.RequireClaim("scope", scope);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the signing certificate as a HTTPS web certificate. The signing cert is only used when IdentityServer signs the JWT tokens.

You need to get a real certificate from a trusted provider (like Lets Encrypt) and install it separately as a TLS/HTTPS certificate.

Signing certs and TLS/HTTPS certificates are separate things that both needs to be configured properly.

Comment: I know we cant use https cert for signing ...thats why i generated a certificate using the mentioned blog post in the question and uploaded it to Azure storage......bothe certs are different.

Comment: You know you can't use the technique in the blog post to generate the HTTPS cert? how did you get the HTTPs cert?  The blog post is only talks about the signing cert.

Comment: Its hosted in Azure and my infra team provided that cert in the domain..  and the blog post said"generate signing cer for Identity server and hence i created and uploaded that cert to Azure app service

Comment: No, its a signing cert for the tokens, you can upload it as a HTTPS cert. Its not valid for that. The signing cert is important, and you can store it in Azure, like in Azure Key Vault, because you need it to be the same across deployment. But its for signing of keys only.

Comment: To be clear, i have an https cer which is different (www.domain.com.pfx) and i uploaded a cert rsacert.pfx as a private cert in the service .. the first 1 is used for https and the uploaded 1 is used as the sign-in cert ...

Comment: You sayin uploading it to a key vault and then using it will solve my problem???

Comment: it might, its always a good practice to store secrets/certificates/keys in a secure and reliable way and Azure Key Vault is a good place to store that kind of information. You can use AKV both for local development and in production. You just need to store the "credentials" for AKV somewhere. like UserSecrets locally and environment variables in Azure.

Comment: Thanks mate! update the issue fixed when i used thesame config and cert in a different subscription (sandbox ,might be issue with app service plan or something...keyvault is in progress infra tema needs to create and share cred with me ...thanks again

Comment: great! feel free to accept or upvote my answer if you feel it helped!